# маршрут для робота

Tags: java, трассировка, маршрут

я делаю игру на **java** в виде 2д бродилки с видом сверху и также в моей игре есть робот надо запрограммировать робота так чтобы он обходил все преграды по короткому маршруту и убивал игрока я использую в качестве массива карты двумерный массив я прочитал эту статью и хочу что нибудь такое https://evileg.com/ru/post/359/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код прикладывать не стал потому что там 1000 строк

Comment: А вопрос в чем? :) В реализации волнового алгоритма (из ссылки в вопросе)? Привели бы пример вашего двухмерного массива, пометили бы что в нем считается преградой и откуда и куда нужно пройти

Comment: int[][] map; есть такой массив карты а также есть блоки 4 и 9 также робот должен обойти преграды 4 и 9 по самому короткому пути и дойти до игрока

Comment: Не, это нужно прямо в вопросе, чтобы был минимальный пример кода. Просто, вряд ли будут желающие по описанию в вашем комментарии воссоздавать такую структуру и за вас делать алгоритм :)

Comment: напишите хоть консольную программу на по этой теме я внедрю её к себе

Comment: Смотрите, на этом сайте принято помогать с задачами, а не решать за кого-то либо. Поэтому, пожалуйста, добавьте вашу попытку решить задачу (в виде кода в вопросе), иначе вопрос может быть закрыт. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Я ранее написал, что от вас ожидается

Comment: В статье по вашей ссылке все расписано. Просто прочтите еще раз медленно и с карандашом в руке и все получится - ничего сложного. Чтобы немного пояснить - ваши клеточки это узлы в статье. Узлы могут быть посещаемыми, или нет, либо уже посещенными (из которой вы пришли). Для следующего шага вы должны проверять клеточки вокруг текущей клетки и выбирать те, которые ближе к цели (если дальше тупик, то следующую по "близости") и так далее до самой цели. Это если коротенько и самая суть

Comment: пусть вопрос закоется потому что я уже решил задачу